# Spring Security - UserDetailsService for oAuth2 implementation?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

So, using a basic authentication, I can see the value in simply using an implementation of the UserDetailsService which basically just loads a user and confirms they are authenticated.

However, I would now like to use oAuth2 and am not sure if my thinking is completely wrong on this subject. Wouldn't using oAuth2 eliminate the need for a UserDetailsService implementation? Because essentially the authorization server is the one who is checking to make sure the user exists (using Resource owner password flow) and then sends the user a JWT.

Once the user has this access token and can send it with every request, there has got to be another way to get the user authenticated into the AuthenticationManager rather than duplicating the effort and checking to make sure the credentials are correct again within the UserDetailsService (which the Authorization Server from oAuth2 would have already one).

What is this other way? What would be a solid implementation for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `UserDetailsService` required for getting user information with his permissions. This is normal behavior. If user passed authorization he receive access token and Spring store his authentication data into `SecurityContext`. When user sends requests to protected resources with token - Spring validates token and puts into SecurityContext authentication data from DB or from memory. Its depends on the type of `TokenStore` (jdbc, memory, etc). Spring security using `UserDetailsService` once for user authorization.